# Adjective for thing you do for others

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

I sometimes write university projects for students and fix friends' computers, sometimes for money. I call things I do for myself *personal projects*, *personal work*, *personal act*, etc.

What adjective should I use to call those things I do for others? *Impersonal* and *nonpersonal* do not sound good.

Comment: If you get paid for them, they could be called **jobs**, or **commissions**. If not, they're **favours**.

Comment: If you get paid for writing university projects for students, this could be *unethical*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm not doing them by force, so they are not comissions. The're not my primary "job", and sometimes I have no interest in the subject so it couldn't be my "favourite".

Comment: @Hugo: Are you a university professor? :)

Comment: I don't know of a word for this.  I would simply say "work for friends" or "work for acquaintances."

Comment: I don't think accepting a paid *commission* implies you're "forced" to do it. But if it's important to make that distinction then all OP's paid work outside his primary job could be either *favours* if the money isn't particularly important, or *sidelines* if the extra money is significant and welcome.

Comment: Your title asks for an adjective but the question body gives noun phrases as examples.  Which are you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Extracurricular*?

If you're labeling folders or the like, I'd probably just stick with *Other*.

Comment: It's a good word but i thought meaning of "Extracurricular" has a taste of sports and physical activities?

Comment: I describe many of my non-work related activities as extracurricular even if they're not sports-related (band practice, web design).  Technically, the word just means anything outside of the curriculum (for whatever curriculum you are prescribing).

Answer (score 1):

You could contrast *personal* projects with *external* projects.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that as opposed to personal projects you could be doing public projects, especially if you don't take any pay for them. You are working to improve the public good, just as you'd be working toward improving your own situation on the personal projects.

Answer (score 1):

*Pro bono* describes projects for which you don't charge. However, if you charge, you could refer to your work as *freelance*.